# prisma Error: p1001: Can't reach database server at `db.xocheossqzkirwnhzxxm.supabase.co`:`5432`

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, supabase-database

I started learning about prisma and supabase and would like to implement both technologies in my Next.js app. After running `npx prisma migrate dev --name init` I was faced with the following error:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env                                                                                                                                            
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "db.xocheossqzkirwnhzxxm.supabase.co:5432"

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db.xocheossqzkirwnhzxxm.supabase.co`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `db.xocheossqzkirwnhzxxm.supabase.co`:`5432`.
```

my password to the db does not contain any special characters here is my schema.prisma file:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Home{
  id        String @id @default(cuid())
  image     String?
  title     String
  description String
  price     Float
  guests    Int
  beds      Int
  baths     Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updateAt  DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

here is my .env:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@db.xocheossqzkirwnhzxxm.supabase.co:5432/postgres"
```

Comment: With a `can't reach` error like this, your username and password never came into play. Something prevented prisma from getting access to your PostgreSQL server over the network. Maybe there's a firewall in the way. Maybe PostgreSQL is using a different port. Maybe it isn't running at all.

Comment: I created my db in supabase.... let me try turning off my fire wall

Comment: Turning off my firewall didn't work @O.Jones

Comment: I experienced the same issue, but the cause was different. Looks like supabase will ban your IP address if you fail to connect multiple times (in my case, with invalid password, I guess). You can see it in supabase under `Project Settings > Database > Network Bans`.
Hope this will help someone as I only noticed the section in settings by accident.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a Sveltekit application using Prisma and PlanetScale (MySQL) and Docker on Windows (WSL). I received the same error but did not have this issue when I ran it directly from terminal nor when I connected through the mysql cli.

## Solution

I ensured that my Docker **Node version was the same as on WSL (16.15)**, I have noticed others have had this issue with different versions of Node so it is worth exploring this. **I then added `connect_timeout=300` to my SQL URL** to prevent the connection from timing out too early.

I include more details in my other [answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73766815/how-to-connect-docker-to-planetscale/73919557#73919557).

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Adding the connection_timeout sadly didn't help still timed out. It works if I connect using the cli mysql or pscale but if I try to access it through Prisma is just fails for some reason. Super weird, still haven't found a solution. Seems the common factor is Prisma + PlanetScale?

Comment: Using `connect_timeut=300` worked! Please change the variable name in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and in my case i was running a VPN (Proton VPN) in background on my local computer.

- The MySQL server was in a Ubuntu server in the cloud.
- I tested also with Planet Scale and the error was the same

I Manage to resolve the problem by stopping the vpn.

Comment: Thank you so much. I encountered the same problem trying to setup planet scale with prisma and couldn't find a fix. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when i try to migrate  my prisma schema to supabase instead of migrating your schema `npx prisma db push`  use this

`npx prisma migrate dev --preview-feature`

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `relationMode = "prisma"` to `schema.prisma` file.

[image: schema.prisma file]

Answer (score 1):

## March 2024. 2 step solution for my project (Next13, Prisma, Supabase, GraphQL)

### 1. Change password for project in Supabase

❌ My old password contained numbers.❌ Have read somewhere that numbers and special characters may cause problem.

Go to [Supabase dashboard settings](https://supabase.com/dashboard/project/_/settings/database) click button "Reset database password" in section "Database password" to change password.

### 2. Change `DATABASE_URL`

```js
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Change `DATABASE_URL` to:
DATABASE_URL=`postgres://[USER]:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@aws-0-eu-west-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/postgres`

You can find your [USER] here [Supabase dashboard settings](https://supabase.com/dashboard/project/_/settings/database)

Helpful [discussion](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/17817)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with supabase, and I just switched to a private net. I was using my University Wifi. Try using your hotspot.

Maybe Docker is hosted in a public net?

Im not sure if thats helps you, but I spent some months trying to fix it, maybe can be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

For people who haven't solved this problem, try to delete and recreate the project on Supabase (I tried to set my password as a chain of digits, regardless not work the first time but after that, I reset my pw with exactly the same with the previous) surprisingly it worked after hours looking for solutions on the internet. Hope you too!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me

After copying the DATABASE_URL from Prisma, you will need to adjust the connection URL slightly to point to your own database.

Basically here is the format

`mysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE`

`DATABASE_URL="mysql://myusername:mypassword@server.us-east-2.psdb.cloud/mydb?*ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":true}*"`

I had to change what was initially written on my Db_Url by adding this **sslaccept=strict** and removing what was written before.

So Your Database_Url should look like this: `DATABASE_URL="mysql://myusername:mypassword@server.us-east-2.psdb.cloud/mydb?sslaccept=strict"`

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue with planetscale connection. Even though I controlled my credentials many times and see that it was exactly the same as my credentials, prisma somehow wasn't able to connect.

[image: prisma error]

I found the source of problem, I started first my t3 application with pnpm, then having some issues with deployment I moved to normal npm and installed it.

When I started using npm, prisma throw this error mentioned in the issue, after turning back to pnpm error disappeared.

[image: prisma working example]

Probably the error is related with prisma client library generation in node_modules, but I can't tell you how ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in my *Next.js 13* app. I **restarted the server** and also tried the push command from my **Ubuntu Terminal** instead of VS Code terminal and it worked for me. Now, I am also able to use this command from VS Code Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me

You have this URL if you are using Supabase and Postgesql
**postgresql://postgres:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@db.qhhlppxdlsbsaotbojei.supabase.co:5432/postgres**

Here in the **password** try to use **string** only like abc or defniacns. **Avoid numbers in your password**. Out of 10 to 15 solutions this worked well for me. And I hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue was that I tried to connect with an incorrect password and Supabase automatically blocked my IP address. After unblocking myself everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding `pgbouncer=true` to my database url. I used neon db and prisma but the same concept should apply.
Example:
`DATABASE_URL='postgresql://xxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.neon.tech/xxxxxxx?sslmode=require&pgbouncer=true'`